# Making part of a touchable transparent with React-Native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I would like to make part of a `Touchable` traslucid, i.e, to be able to see the background behind it.

A possible hack is to use `MaskedView` and draw my background again, inside the `Touchable`, as the `children` prop to `MaskedView`. However, this only works for a limited number of scenarios. Here it is working:

[image]

However, as soon as I add some margin, for example, things get out of phase:

[image]

A couple clarifications, just in case:

- My real intention is to use a gradient which goes between opposite corners of the screen. In that case, things don't work even in the simple scenario I presented.
- I know why this hack doesn't work, but I haven't been able to come up with anything better

Here is a MWE, using a view instead of an image, so that I don't need to bundle the `png` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

export default function () {
    return (
        <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
                        colors={['red', 'blue', 'green']}
                        style={
                            {flex: 1,
                            alignItems: 'stretch',
                            justifyContent: 'center'}
                        }>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={
                    {height: 100,
                    alignItems: 'stretch',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderRadius: 30,
                    //marginLeft: 50, // -> if you uncomment this line, the translucid effect is ruined
                    }
                }>
                    <MaskedView
                        style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                            alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}
                        maskElement={
                            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',
                            }}>
                                <View style={{width: 300, height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>
                            </View>
                        }
                    >
                        <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
                                        colors={['red', 'blue', 'green']}
                                        style={{height: '100%'}}
                        />
                     </MaskedView>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why not set the top level `View` under `TouchableOpacity` to have `background: transparent`, and then render in children `View`s with solid color backgrounds?

Comment: @zaytrix I'm sorry, but I don't get what you mean. Could you modify the MWE with your suggestion and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an expo snack to illustrate my comment: https://snack.expo.io/SkCNR7Iqr

The idea is, rather than rendering and then hiding content, just don't render anything there in the first place. This will render the white ends within the bounds of the button. The wrapper uses `overflow: 'hidden'` to ensure that the Touchable effect will only appear within the bounded `borderRadius` (more noticeable with TouchableHighlight), and it will ensure that the white ends and any other content in it will stay within the bounded `borderRadius`.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={['red', 'blue', 'green']}
        style={styles.gradient}>
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touch}>
            <View style={styles.end} />
            <View style={styles.content} />
            <View style={styles.end} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  wrapper: {
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 30,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginLeft: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  touch: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  },
  end: {
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '100%',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @zaytrix! Unfortunately, I don't see how I could apply your approach to anything more complicated than a view (e.g., some text, or an image). I've updated my question, to show an example using an image. Do you think there is any way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. So for your `MaskedView` hack, the reason why it goes out of phase is because you're rendering another `LinearGradient` below the mask, bounded by the `TouchableOpacity`. Not sure if there's a way to do this as a mask, my suggestion would be to create another image that is the height of the `TouchableOpacity` and width of the original image, filled with white, and with a cutout of the original image. That way you can place that in the middle, and use flex to fill the width of the side `View`s